# Add-Migration not generating EF script from model in MVC Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using ASP.Net MVC Core 3 with Entity Framework and SQL Server. I have been building the supporting database in Azure using Add-Migration and Update-Database in VS 2019 Package Manager Console. I have several model classes that have been used successfully to generate the migration code. However, I have a model from which are generated empty Up() and Down() methods in the migration class. The model is public, and all of its member properties are public. I'm really baffled as to what could be happening.

Here's the model:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MapItGo_Web_App.Models {
    public class ShippingRequestModel {

        public long ShippingRequestModelID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your First Name")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public String FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your Last Name")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public String LastName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your Email Address")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public String Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your Phone Number")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public string PhoneNumber {get; set;}

        [StringLength(2500)]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Comments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a `DbContext` file and have you defined a `DbSet` property for this class?

Comment: @ShawnOrr - DbSet was the issue. I have a DbContext. I just needed to add the DbSet for ShippingRequestModel. Funny. I don't remember doing that at all with the other models, but they're there. I've been all over the place with this project.... Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ShawnOrr points out below, I needed to add the DbSet for ShippingRequestModel to my DbContext class. That did the trick.

```
        public DbSet<ShippingRequestModel> ShippingRequests { get; set; }
```

Thanks, Shawn!